# What information is necessary in system-user.dtsi from pl.dtsi

Tags: embedded-linux, hardware

```
{
amba_pl: amba_pl {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;
    compatible = "simple-bus";
    ranges ;
    axi_dma_0: dma@40400000 {
        #dma-cells = <1>;
        clock-names = "s_axi_lite_aclk", "m_axi_sg_aclk", "m_axi_mm2s_aclk", "m_axi_s2mm_aclk";
        clocks = <&clkc 15>, <&clkc 15>, <&clkc 15>, <&clkc 15>;
        compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-7.1", "xlnx,axi-dma-1.00.a";
        interrupt-names = "mm2s_introut", "s2mm_introut";
        interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
        interrupts = <0 29 4 0 30 4>;
        reg = <0x40400000 0x10000>;
        xlnx,addrwidth = <0x20>;
        xlnx,include-sg ;
        xlnx,sg-length-width = <0xe>;
        dma-channel@40400000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-mm2s-channel";
            dma-channels = <0x1>;
            interrupts = <0 29 4>;
            xlnx,datawidth = <0x20>;
            xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
        };
        dma-channel@40400030 {
            compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-s2mm-channel";
            dma-channels = <0x1>;
            interrupts = <0 30 4>;
            xlnx,datawidth = <0x20>;
            xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
        };
    };
};
```

};

The above code is in pl.dtsi, created by petalinux from the .xsa file. But to build the boot image I need to update this information in system-user.dtsi. Can anyone help me to write the system-user.dtsi file from the above pl.dtsi?

Comment: The `i` in the filename extension **.dtsi** stands for `include`. You're expected to simply use a preprocessor directive to include a **.dtsi** file in the **.dts** or another **.dtsi** file.

Comment: @sawdust https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18842490/Testing+UIO+with+Interrupt+on+Zynq+Ultrascale  As per the link we will have to add the &axi_dma_0 node,  How to add interrept information from the ip.dsi into the .dtsi node?

Comment: "*As per the link we will have to add the &axi_dma_0 node*" -- No, that link mentions nothing about "*axi_dma_0*". "*How to add interrept information from the ip.dsi ...*" -- What is "*ip.dsi*"? Seems like **system-user.dtsi** is used to consolidate all user customizations to the DT. Thus you do not have to modify/patch any DT files in the kernel source. So you can use a node label, such as `&axi_dma_0` to add, redefine, or delete a property of an existing node. But your post doesn't make much sense without knowing which **.dts** file you are using for your board and your intent.

Comment: @sawdust sorry ip.dsi is a typo. I meant pl.dtsi. I learnt how to update the system-user.dtsi file but never able to boot linux into the board.  The following error was never resolved :   Connection refused                                                                     
    while executing
"error $message"
    (procedure "connect" line 143)
    invoked from within
"connect -url TCP:127.0.0.1:3121"
    (file "/tmp/tmp.uxLFR9Q6w7" line 2)